# search field with comma separted values in model for yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tbles

```
1.users(userid,username)
2.movie(movieid,moviename,viewerid)
```

I am new to YII,want to display gridview with search.

I have table movie ,in which viewerid filed contain id of users like 1,2,3

Another table users having userid,username corresponding to this.

I have to serach inside grid view of  model 'movie' for viewers using name.

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [YII CActiveDataProvider with relational tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402623/yii-cactivedataprovider-with-relational-tables)

Comment: Simple. Don't have comma-separated values in a MySQL table.